# Production Error but not in Pre-Production

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I've got something wierd, my app using Angular and Firestore works correctly in localhost, but when it gets in production, the above function gets into .then but also into .catch error, and it doesn´t go on..

```
login(email:string,password:string){
    this.email=email;
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    .then(value => {
      console.log('Nice, it worked!');
      this.navigate();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      Swal.fire({
        type: 'info',
        title: 'Información:',
        text: 'Revisa por favor la contraseña o correo ingresado',
        footer: 'no coinciden!'
      });
    });
  }
```

Any help please :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I am seeing that it works, maybe it was because I made a new deploy using ng build, without --prod tag

Answer (score 0):

You should log `err` to see what its message contains. And then probably re-throw it or return a rejected promise, because `login()` should not return success if there was an error.